# How to detect a pattern in mp3 and trim

Tags: bash, mp3

```
#!/bin/bash

for X in *.mp3
do
    total_secs=`mp3info -p "%02S" "$X"`
    secs_minus_eight=$(($total_secs - 8))
    mins=$(($secs_minus_eight / 60))
    rounded_secs=$(($mins * 60))
    leftover_secs=$(($secs_minus_eight - $rounded_secs))
    mp3splt "$X" 0.0 $mins.$leftover_secs -o @f "$X" -d ./Shortened/
done
```

I used above bash script(using mp3split,mp3info) to trim last 8 seconds of .mp3 files in a directory. 
How can i modify the script further to scan the whole mp3 and delete matching sections to the final 8 seconds.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the tools and not bash. Try man mp3info

Comment: @simson man mp3info is not relevant. It simply gives the total duration of the file.

Comment: Let see if I understand: you have 8 seconds at the start of the tracks that might be (exactly?) the same at the end of the track. If this is the case, you want to strip them at both ends?

Comment: @sylvain yes it is exactly 8 seconds. The idea us to delete If the 8s portion  appears anywhere in the file. Initial reference is taken from the last 8s.

Comment: @rushdee I'm afraid this is beyond my knowledge. However, one thing is still puzzling me: are you sure that start and end sequences are _exactly_ the same? Can't there been some compression artifact that made them different (at raw binary level -- maybe even after audio stream decompression)?